# Python import from different directory

Tags: python, import

This has been discussed to eternity here and I've tried the recommended solutions but I'm still running into a wall.

I'm playing around with the [OpenBMP](https://github.com/OpenBMP/openbmp-mrt) package and while attempting to run the main program I get the error `ImportError: No module named mrt.logger`.

I'm running the program `src/bin/openbmp-mrt` while the file to be imported is located at `src/site-packages/openbmp/mrt/logger`.

The import statement is:
`from openbmp.mrt.logger import LoggerThread`

Here is the tree of the `src` directory:

```
`-- src
    |-- bin
    |   `-- openbmp-mrt
    |-- etc
    |   `-- openbmp-mrt.yml
    `-- site-packages
        `-- openbmp
            |-- __init__.py
            `-- mrt
                |-- bgp.py
                |-- bmp_bgp4mp.py
                |-- bmp_consumer.py
                |-- bmp.py
                |-- db_mysql.py
                |-- __init__.py
                |-- logger.py
                |-- mrt_bgp4mp_object.py
                |-- mrt_table_dump.py
                `-- RawTimedRotatingFileHandler.py
```

So far I've tried:

1. Appending the fully qualified path of `src/site-packages/` to
   sys.path
2. Adding a `__init__.py` file to `src/site-packages/`

But I'm still getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you from `from openbmp.mrt import logger` and use as `logger.LoggerThread`?

Comment: When I try `from openbmp.mrt import logger` I get `ImportError: No module named mrt`.

Comment: Have you called your script `openbmp.py`? If so, you need to rename it. If not, then the author hasn't made their library particularly easy to use.

Comment: Are you in a virtual environment? And are you certain the file you are trying to import is something you can actually import?

Comment: @roganjosh The script I'm calling is `openbmp-mrt` from `src/bin`. The `openbmp` is a directory within `src/site-packages` which contains the `mrt` directory which in turn contains the module I'm trying to import

Comment: No, I mean the name of your own python file in which you're trying to import into

Comment: The python file I'm running is `openbmp-mrt` - are you saying this needs to be renamed to openbmp.py??

Comment: Hold on, wires crossed here I think. You're trying to run one of the files that's inside the actual library directly?

Comment: @K-Log No, I'm not in a virtualenv. I fired up a Python terminal from within `src/site-packages` and I was able to successfully run `from openbmp.mrt.logger import LoggerThread`

Comment: @roganjosh Yes - the file I'm trying to run is `src/bin/openbmp-mrt` which is in the actual library

Comment: In the README there are installation instructions. I don't think that file is intended to be run independently. If you've followed the instructions to install, try importing the package into a script of your own.

Comment: From the README: `If you are running from within the git directory, you can run it as follows:

PYTHONPATH=./src/site-packages python src/bin/openbmp-mrt -c src/etc/openbmp-mrt.yml`

Comment: Yeah I went to the bottom and saw that too after. I don't know enough about what that package should be doing so I can't make sense of the usage it describes sorry.

Comment: Maybe you need to add it to your PYTHONPATH before ou can import it? Or maybe there’s a setup file somewhere that can set everything up for you?

Comment: @K-Log I tried that too but it didn't work. I ended up copying the library to the same directory and that fixed things. Granted it's probably the worst way to get this fixed but I couldn't spend more time on this. I'll probably get back to figuring this out when I'm done with the more important tasks of this project